# How to fire a get request between rails and ember

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I am new to frontend development,I am using rails and ember to built  a sample app .

in rails , i have a function as below

```
def get_id 
      first_id = User.first.id
     render json: { id: first_id , type: "master"} 
end
```

I want to fire a GET request from ember side to call the get_id in ember side which will return the required response . thanks .

Comment: What you are asking for is a complete ember tutorial. Thats out of scope for stackoverflow. https://guides.emberjs.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your User models defined in both your Rails and Ember apps, you have a Rails DB seeded with User objects, and you're using Ember Data within your Ember application, to actually make a GET http request you would theoretically need to make this call:

```
this.store.findRecord('User', id);
```

Where `id` is the id of the User you'd like to retrieve.

If you need more guidance on setting up your models, etc. this guide would be a great place to start: https://emberigniter.com/modern-bridge-ember-and-rails-5-with-json-api/